# How do I perform a calculation with a distinct ID in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Wasn't sure how to ask this question. Basically I have a table:

```
create table sales (
bookcode int not null,
storecode int not null,
saledate date not null,
quantity int not null,
price decimal,
foreign key (bookcode) references books(bookcode),
foreign key (storecode) references stores(storecode)
);
```

and what I'm trying to do here is calculate the revenue for each store code. It will multiply the quantity by the price which is fine but I don't know how to get it so if there are multiple of the same storecode, it groups them together and gives a total amount

For example: if there are two stores in the sales table with the same store code of 1, I want to get the revenue of both and have them show up as a mass total for that storecode, instead of showing them separately. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is a `GROUP BY` clause, e.g.

```
SELECT storecode, SUM(quantity * price) AS total_sales
    FROM sales
    GROUP BY storecode;
```

This clause directs the SQL engine to group together rows which have an identical `storecode`, then apply aggregate functions to combine the results from each set of rows. In this case, the aggregate function used is `SUM()`; other common aggregate functions include `COUNT()`, `AVG()`, `MIN()`, `MAX()`, and `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

Keep in mind that, if you're using a `GROUP BY` clause, every column you select must be either one of the values that's being `GROUP`ed `BY`, or an aggregate function. For instance, you could not:

```
SELECT storecode, saledate FROM sales GROUP BY storecode  /* no! */
```

because `saledate` is neither a column that's being grouped by, nor an aggregate function. (To put it simply: there's multiple sale dates, which one is the query engine supposed to give you?)

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked exactly as I wanted. I missed the class where we went over that so this is perfect!

Comment: If you missed that lecture, you may also want to read up on the `HAVING` clause, which is closely related to `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
SELECT storecode, SUM(price*quantity) as revenue FROM sales GROUP BY storecode;
```

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sales` (
  `bookcode` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `storecode` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `saledate` date NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal

) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `sales` (`bookcode`, `storecode`, `saledate`, `quantity`, `price`) VALUES
  ('1', '1', '2017-09-24',3,5),
  ('1', '1', '2017-09-24',5,5),
  ('1', '2', '2017-09-24',10,5),
  ('1', '2', '2017-09-24',10,10);

select storecode,sum(quantity*price)as income from sales group by storecode